# java script add to list when button clicked

Tags: javascript, list, button

the console print:

`code` Uncaught TypeError: event.cancelBubble is not a function
at HTMLDocument.bringBackDefault (new_rightclick.js:87:31)`code`

how can i solve the problem ?
i'm trying to make a button that add item to a list every click

Comment: Can you share code its hard to know like this, add your code here https://playcode.io/javascript  and share url

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. As suggested by @loki, could you please share your codebase around this.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.